# Problem with install4j smart card EV code signing

Tags: linux, maven, code-signing, install4j

We need to add EV signing to Our Install4j Maven build, which runs on Fedora.
So far in our .install4j file we have

```
<codeSigning windowsEnabled="true"
     verbose="true"
     windowsKeySource="pkcs11"
     windowsPkcs11Library="/usr/lib/pkcs11/libIDPrimePKCS11.so"
     winKeystorePassword="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
     <windowsPkcs11Identifier issuer="GlobalSign GCC R45 EV CodeSigning CA 2020"
                                      serial="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
                                      subject="ZZZZZZZZZZ" />
</codeSigning>
```

but we're getting

```
[INFO] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: The certificate file /usr/lib/pkcs11/libIDPrimePKCS11.so does not exist.
```

The file does exist, and `keytool` can see it.

Comment: This is only printed if new File("/usr/lib/pkcs11/libIDPrimePKCS11.so").exists() returns false, can you double check the file name, maybe its capitalization? Could it be that the user that runs the build cannot access this directory?

Comment: All this stuff is buried in a Docker image, but when I shell into the Docker I get

```
   
 [root@9f82417ffc17 /]# jshell
    |  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.11
    |  For an introduction type: /help intro
    jshell> new File("/usr/lib/pkcs11/libIDPrimePKCS11.so").exists()
    $3 ==> true

    jshell>

```

Comment: Going to deep-dive into the Docker. Something here makes no sense; that library should be public-read.

Comment: Located the problem; the wrong Docker image was being loaded. 

Now I'm seeing:

install4j: compilation failed. Reason: com.install4j.d.j: java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found

In the native Fedora, 
keytool -list -v -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -providerclass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg etoken

Works if I provide the token password when prompted.  How do I provide the token password in this environment? I'm guessing I need the etoken config file present when the Install4J compile runs...

Comment: The password is passed to install4jc with the argument `--win-keystore-password`

Comment: Ok, as you can see we're doing that. I wonder why we're getting the "PKCS11 not found" exception... perhaps the providerArg file, but all that's in that is 

name=etoken
library=/usr/lib/pkcs11/libIDPrimePKCS11.so
slot=0

Comment: Maybe the PKCS11 library does not have access to the HSM in the Docker image? You can build with verbose mode to get a stacktrace that may reveal an underlying cause.